# .net core application running on Azure using AAD keep looping for authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

i have created a simple dot net core MVC application which is built by visualstudio 2019 at the start of project creation. i am hosting the application on azure app service using Azure active directory. when i log in to AAD it let me sign in and gives a welcome message You have successfully signed in RETURN TO THE WEBSITE. when i return to website, it does the same thing again comes back to same screen.

[image]

The only change i have manually added is the client ID with the one that i have registered in AAD with redirecturi as "https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback".

here's my appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<myid>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<mt tenant>",
    "RedirectUri": "https://<myappname>.azurewebsites.net",
    "ClientId": "<my client from aad>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Here's the code from startup

```
namespace Yellalebros
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you avoid any configuration errors with using sign-in flow with Microsoft code sample?
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC

There is also a quickstart guide for "Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app", did you go through all the steps?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `redirecturi` in azure ad
from
`https://.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

to
`https://.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc`.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) about add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i changed the way suggested above, but now i am getting below error.

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '95689c9a-465b-4f11-ae91-2dda44256bf9'.